# Getting a list of objects in Hibernate returns a list of a single object

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, hql

I am using Hibernate in my Spring Java EE application. I get the list of Users, where User is a bean specified in the applicationContext.xml as follows:

```
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>
            <value>foo.bar.User</value>
        </list>
    </property>
```

The code that returns the list of users is the following; the returned list has the correct size, however all the objects seem to be the same object (I'm printing out the objects in my JSF file using ui:repeat.

```
public List<User> getAllUsers() {

    Query q = currentSession().createQuery("from User");

    List<User> allUsers = (List<User>) q.list();

    return allUsers;

}
```

I suspect that the User is returned a single time, however cannot resolve the issue.

How can I make a Hibernate query to return all objects?

Comment: The Hibernate code seems fine. What does it print if you log all the IDs of the returned users? There mst be something wrong in your JSF logic.

Comment: Thanks a lot, the Hibernate code is correct indeed, I have found my problem, it is quite embarrassing, though; since it is a silly mistake. See my comment below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I had changed the primary key value, which was user_id to id. This caused the id column to be set to all zeros, hence it was always returning the 0'th object.